# Duda sobre JavaScript y su uso

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const contenedor = document.querySelector('#contenedor');

document.querySelector('#boton-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
    contenedor.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* BARRA CABECERO */

.contenedor{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.cabecero{
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 8px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* MENU, LOGO - START */

.cabecero .start{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.cabecero .start .boton-menu{
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.cabecero .start .boton-menu:hover{
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.cabecero .start .logo .bi{
    position: relative;
    color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 2px;
    top: 1.5px;
}

.cabecero .start .logo{
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cabecero .start .supindice{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    position: relative;
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 11px;
    top: -4px;
    left: 4px;
}

/* BUSCADOR, LUPA - CENTRO*/

.cabecero .centro{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.cabecero .centro .buscador{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cabecero .centro .buscador input{
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: inherit;
    border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 25vw;
}

.cabecero .centro .buscador input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgb(2, 98, 158);
}

.cabecero .centro .buscador button{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 37px;
    width: 55px;
}

.cabecero .centro .buscador button:hover{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.cabecero .centro .boton-micro{
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.cabecero .centro .boton-micro:hover{
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

/* SUBIR, NOTI, CUENTA - FINAL */

.cabecero .final{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 24px;
}

.cabecero .final button{
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.cabecero .final button:hover{
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

.menu-lateral{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 220px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.menu-lateral a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 15px 35px;
}

.menu-lateral a:hover{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.menu-lateral a.active{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-lateral a.active .bi{
    color: #ff0000;
}

.menu-lateral .bi{
    margin-right: 32px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-lateral .separador{
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor" class="contenedor active">
    <header class="cabecero">
        <nav class="start">
            <button id="boton-menu" class="boton-menu"><i class="bi bi-list"></i></button>
            <a href="/" class="logo" title="Pagina de inicio YouTube"><i class="bi bi-youtube"></i><span>YouTube<sup class="supindice">AR</sup></span></a>
            <!-- <a href="#" class="logo"><i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i></i><span>YouTube</span></a> -->
        </nav>

        <nav class="centro">
            <div class="buscador">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
                <button type="submit"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
            </div>
            <button class="boton-micro"><i class="bi bi-mic-fill"></i></button>
        </nav>

        <nav class="final">
            <button><i class="bi bi-cloud-plus"></i></button>
            <button><i class="bi bi-bell"></i></button>
            <button><i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i></button>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <nav class="menu-lateral">
        <a href="/" class="active"><i class="bi bi-house-door-fill"></i>Inicio</a>
        <a href="/"><i class="bi bi-bookmarks"></i>Shorts</a>
        <a href="/"><i class="bi bi-collection-play"></i>Suscripciones</a>

        <hr class="separador">

        <a href="/"><i class="bi bi-stack"></i>Mi biblioteca</a>
        <a href="/"><i class="bi bi-clock-history"></i>Historial</a>
        <a href="/"><i class="bi bi-arrow-right-square"></i>Mis videos</a>
        <a href="/"><i class="bi bi-clock"></i>Ver mas tarde</a>
        <a href="/"><i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i>Mostrar mas</a>

        <hr class="separador">
    </nav>
</div>
```

Mi problema es el siguiente. Lo que quiero es que al hacer click en el boton que tiene **id="boton-menu"** el **menu-lateral** se achique y solo queden sus iconos. O sea, achicar el ancho del menu lateral al hacer click en el **menu**. No se si me falto definir un ancho u algo posteriormente en **"contenedor"**. Tampoco se nada de javascript, solo vi eso y queria tentar a probar a ver que me salia, la cosa es que se desplaza, pero si uso:

```
.contenedor.active{
  ajusto ancho con width; 
}
```

Lo que hace es centrarme todo en el medio porque cambia el ancho de toda la pagina. No se como hacer que solo el menu lateral sea el que cambie su tamaño cuando hago el click.  Como puedo hacer esto?

La persona de la que me estoy guiando uso css grid, se que el tiene definido algo en contenedor.active Es lo siguiente:

```
.contenedor {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(90px, 90px) auto;
    grid-template-rows: 60px auto;
    grid-template-areas: "header header"
                         "menu contenido";
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.contenedor.active {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, 18%) auto;
}
```

No se si hay un efecto en eso de grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, 18%) que le ajusta el tamaño de su columna al hacer el click o como se manejaria. Yo estoy usando, como se ve, display:flex.

Comment: Te conviene mejor hacer un slide, si lo que quieres es contraer y expandir el menú, puedes comenzar investigando por ahí.

Comment: Si, igual ahi encontre el error, el usa columnas ya desde contenedor, yo al usar flexbox pues tenia que aplicarlo pero en el div de lateral, yo lo aplicaba como el en el contenedor que tiene grid (en su caso). Igual voy a investigar eso, gracias.